# Правило образования окончания (находящейся или находящемся)

Tags: орфография, окончания, переводы

Есть предложение (перевод документации):

Кликните средней кнопкой мышки на стрелке или названии вида, **находящейся** (или находящемся) на панели инструментов.

Интересует, каким должно быть правильное окончание "находящейся", по какому правилу оно образуется.

Comment: Middle-click the arrow or the name of the view on the viewport toolbar.
____
Если для вас это грубый жаргон, то приведите пример как должно быть.
____
Вот ссылка на изображение (для наглядности) http://i63.fastpic.ru/big/2014/1012/57/9ed1c50cbd786db5e0b7645a864d2a57.png

Comment: >Middle-click the arrow or the name of the view on the viewport toolbar.  
  
Ясно. Сейчас. Ответ дам в тесте своего ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно пишется: кликните по стрелке (Д.п.).

Кликните средней кнопкой мышки по стрелке или названию вида, находящемуся  на панели инструментов.

Это если на панели инструментов только название вида. В противном случае - мн.число (находящимся).

Answer (score 1):

Ой, behemothus, с жаргоном, а тем более грубым, вы загнули.

1. КЛИКАТЬ, кличу, кличешь; нсв. -кну, -нет; св. [от англ. to click - нажимать]. ***Разг. информ.***
2. что и по чему.
   Нажимать клавишу мыши.
    2.
       Нажимать на клавишу, чтобы открыть какой-л. файл. К. адрес. < Кликнуть, -ну, -нешь; св. Однокр.

(***Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
               Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.
             Первое издание: СПб.: Норинт, 1998).***

Comment: Что касается перевода, то, конечно, перевод небезупречен с стилистической точки зрения. Однако автора интересовало окончания. София дала исчерпывающий ответ.

Comment: Есть идеи, как отполировать предложение (в стилистическом плане)?

Comment: >Ой, behemothus, с жаргоном, 
  
@Серж, "кликать ***по стрелке***" - это грубый жаргон. Даже не профессиональный жаргон, ламерский. Слово "кликать" - разговорное. К нему претензий не имею. Имею большие претензии к словарю Кузнецова. Но это уже отдельная песня.  
  
>...окончание. София дала исчерпывающий ответ.   
  
Даже в этой постановке ответ неполный, чтобы не сказать неправильный. Окончание зависит от смысла, а он устанавливается только оригинальным текстом. весьма вероятно, "находящейся" относится к стрелке, а "название вида" вообще попало туда по недоразумению.

Comment: >Есть идеи как отполировать предложение (в стилистическом плане)?  
  
Нельзя править стиль, пока не ясен смысл.
Простите, только что увидел оригинал. Сейчас разберемся.

Answer (score 0):

Оригинал есть? Смысл переведенной фразы как-то не очень понятен.  Если стрелка - это курсор, то перевод заведомо некорректен, что бы там ни имелось в виду в оригинале.

Ко всему прочему,  "кликнуть по стрелке (, находящейся)" - это не просто разговорная речь, это грубый жаргон. Смысл которого, кстати, сам по себе не совсем понятен.

Ели отвлечься от смысла и ограничится грамматикой, то см. у Софии.

(+)
**!!!**

> Middle-click the arrow or the name of the view on the viewport toolbar.

***Кликните средней кнопкой мыши стрелку(треугольник) или название представления на панели [выбора] области просмотра.***

или

***Кликните средней кнопкой мыши стрелку(треугольник) или название области просмотра на панели области просмотра.***

Комментарии.

***view*** - слово очень многозначное, но "вид" в контексте наименее удачно. Здесь предлагаю ***просмотр*** или ***представление***.

***"name of the view"*** - это ***название стиля или объекта, назначенного к просмотру***. Не могу навскидку сказать, что именно - "стиль" или "объект" здесь имеется в виду, поэтому даю перевод на оба случая. Хотя есть подозрение, что здесь как раз ***название области просмотра*** будет актуальным.

Но если по всей документации "view" переводится как "вид", то ничем помочь не могу. Придется смириться. Только оговорите это понимание.

А ***viewport*** - это область просмотра или порт просмотра. Других  переводов нет и быть не может.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Лично мне слово представление тоже нравится больше и в некоторых местах я его успешно использую. Но в тоже время "представление" носит более "общий" характер. Ну например трехмерное представление элементов сцены. Или например иерархическое (древовидное) представление данных.

Comment: Вид в данном случае носит более конкретный характер, как вид сверху(снизу). Изометрический вид. Перспективный вид. Очень сложно найти золотую середину. Название представления звучит как-то коряво. Название области просмотра звучит вполне. Хотя тут можно поспорит поскольку вид может встраиваться в эту область просмотра а может и существовать в виде о дельного плавающего окна. В любом случае спасибо за помощь и пищу для размышлений. Извиняюсь за ошибки, экран на телефоне мелкий.

Answer (score 0):

Кликните кнопкой мыши по стрелке или по изображению, находящемуся в области просмотра.

Comment: Спасибо. Но это слишком расплывчатый перевод. Во-первых, очень важно какая именно кнопка мышки используется (это ведь техническая документация). Во-вторых в области просмотра (вьюпорте) нет никакого изображения. Есть панель инструментов расположенная в верхней части области просмотра на которой расположены иконки и кнопки.

Comment: Не, ну "средней кнопкой" - уже сказали, это понятно.

Вот name of the view - не очень понятно, что такое. Но уж никак не "имя вида". View - явно "изображение".

Comment: Там именно "название вида" (например вид спереди, вид сверху). Эти понятия абсолютно точно прописаны в учебниках по черчению/инженерной графике. В контексте данной программы view часто используется как синоним viewport. В любом случае всем спасибо за помощь.

Comment: >View - явно "изображение".  
  
Нет. См. текст моего ответа.